# MEAN Stack not working on CentOS 6.10 (multiple errors)

Tags: centos, mean-stack

In CentOS 6.10 x86_64 ,i've installed the MEAN Stack (github/meanjs/mean) &  im facing this unusual error while running the command npm start.
The server will start with 47 error and at last it will endup in the 0.0.0.0:3000 . and i've changed to working domain , but still no use.
Even i used the `--fix` no use , still with `--fix force` also no effect .
If i add a domain like `www.example.com` or the IP address `123.45.678.10` , it ends up in whole lot new errors.

Below is the output of the console

```
npm start

> meanjs@0.6.0 start /home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean
> gulp

[05:00:11] Using gulpfile /home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/gulpfile.js
[05:00:11] Starting 'default'...
[05:00:11] Starting 'env:dev'...
[05:00:11] Finished 'env:dev' after 497 μs
[05:00:11] Starting 'copyLocalEnvConfig'...
[05:00:11] Starting 'makeUploadsDir'...
[05:00:11] Finished 'makeUploadsDir' after 423 μs
[05:00:11] Finished 'copyLocalEnvConfig' after 72 ms
[05:00:11] Starting 'lint'...
[05:00:11] Starting 'less'...
[05:00:12] Finished 'less' after 1.04 s
[05:00:12] Starting 'sass'...
[05:00:12] Finished 'sass' after 304 ms
[05:00:12] Starting 'csslint'...
[05:00:13] Starting 'eslint'...
(node:28244) DeprecationWarning: [eslint] The 'ecmaFeatures' config file property is deprecated, and has no effect. (found in airbnb/legacy)
[05:00:14] Finished 'csslint' after 1.92 s
[05:00:20]
/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/gulpfile.js
  120:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent
  121:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent

/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/modules/users/server/config/strategies/google.js
  21:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent
  22:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  23:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  24:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  25:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  27:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  28:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  29:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  30:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  31:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  32:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  33:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  34:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  35:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  36:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  37:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8  indent
  38:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  41:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6  indent
  42:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent

/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/modules/core/client/services/interceptors/auth-interceptor.client.service.js
  34:21  error  Multiple spaces found before '// Handle erro...'  no-multi-spaces

/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/modules/users/tests/server/user.server.model.tests.js
  263:1  error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6    indent
  264:1  error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8   indent
  265:1  error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8   indent
  266:1  error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 10  indent
  267:1  error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8   indent
  268:1  error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6    indent
  269:1  error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6    indent
  270:1  error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8   indent
  271:1  error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6    indent

/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/modules/users/tests/server/user.server.routes.tests.js
  487:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  488:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  490:1  error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 14  indent
  491:1  error  Expected indentation of 18 spaces but found 16  indent
  492:1  error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 14  indent
  494:1  error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 14  indent
  496:1  error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 14  indent
  497:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  521:1  error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 10  indent
  522:1  error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 10  indent
  524:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  525:1  error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 14  indent
  526:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  528:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  530:1  error  Expected indentation of 14 spaces but found 12  indent
  531:1  error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 10  indent

✖ 47 problems (47 errors, 0 warnings)
  47 errors, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

[05:00:20] Finished 'eslint' after 7.42 s
[05:00:20] Finished 'lint' after 8.86 s
[05:00:20] Starting 'nodemon'...
[05:00:20] Finished 'nodemon' after 129 ms
[05:00:20] Starting 'watch'...
[05:00:20] Finished 'watch' after 270 ms
[05:00:20] Finished 'default' after 9.34 s
[05:00:20] [nodemon] 1.11.0
[05:00:20] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[05:00:20] [nodemon] ignoring: /home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/.git/**/* .nyc_output .sass-cache bower_components coverage /home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/node_modules/**/*
[05:00:20] [nodemon] watching: modules/*/server/views/*.html server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js modules/*/server/config/*.js
[05:00:20] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,html
[05:00:20] [nodemon] starting `node --inspect server.js`
[05:00:20] [nodemon] child pid: 28258
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/f25bcd4b-d765-42db-9b0a-9e506a9c1045
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[05:00:21] [nodemon] watching 175 files


+ Important warning: config.domain is empty. It should be set to the fully qualified domain of the app.
--
MEAN.JS - Development Environment

Environment:     development
Server:          http://0.0.0.0:3000
Database:        mongodb://localhost/mean-dev
App version:     0.6.0
MEAN.JS version: 0.6.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *47 errors* are gnerated by eslint which checks for indentation rules comliance.

i.e.

`/home/mykampaign/public_html/testplan/mean/gulpfile.js
  120:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent`

means you are using 4 spaces instead than 2 at line 120

Since you don't want to modify meanjs code you could change eslint config or disable it.

Comment: How to disable it ?

Comment: so these errors wont affect that much ?  and what about the `Important warning: config.domain is empty. It should be set to the fully qualified domain of the app.
--`   even that also not working .I've changed it in `default.js` inside the `env`' folder but still no use.      What domain i want to use so that it will work.

Comment: They are meant to block the build in order to comply with formatting rules. You can configure eslint to simply ignore indentation using `"indent": "off"`or entirely disable some rules for files matching a glob pattern https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files

Comment: About `config.domain` you can set the DOMAIN env variable or a config entry named `domain` to the domain you are serving i.e. `testplan.mykampaign.co`